# How to give a type signature to polymorphic functions when PolyKinds is enabled?

Tags: haskell, ghc, generic-programming

When enabling `PolyKinds`, previously valid type signatures can become invalid.

The following code compiles without `PolyKinds`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
import GHC.Generics

foo :: Constructor c => t c (f :: * -> *) a -> [Char]
foo = conName
```

When I enable `PolyKinds` it fails to compile.

```
Kind incompatibility when matching types:
  t0 :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
  t :: * -> (* -> *) -> k -> *
Expected type: t c f a -> [Char]
  Actual type: t0 c f a0 -> [Char]
Relevant bindings include
  foo :: t c f a -> [Char] (bound at Gen.hs:8:1)
In the expression: conName
In an equation for ‘foo’: foo = conName
```

Is there a way to give a type signature for `foo` when `PolyKinds` is enabled?

Comment: `foo :: Constructor c => (t :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *) c (f :: * -> *) a -> [Char]` works, bug or feature?

Comment: Yeah, that should work too, since the kinds are inferred from place to place within the signature it doesn't matter on which type variable you fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the discrepancy is

```
t0 :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *
t :: * -> (* -> *) -> k -> *
```

That is, in one of the signatures GHC thinks that the third argument of `t` should have kind `*`, and in the other it thinks it should have polymorphic kind `k`.

I think that the former signature (with `*`) comes from `conName`, while the latter with `k` implicitly comes from your signature for `foo` – the `k` appears because now that you have `PolyKinds` enabled, all your type signatures are interpreted with polymorphic kinds when possible. Also, by design, a signature is considered to give the the full "API" for a function, which means no attempt to infer the kind from the rest of the function is done when you specify the signature explicitly.

In your signature the third argument of the `t` type is `a`, so you can fix it by adding a kind annotation to that to make it consistent with what `conName` wants:

```
foo :: Constructor c => t c (f :: * -> *) (a :: *) -> [Char]
foo = conName
```